# I cant have more than 3 tabs in CKEditor 4

Tags: dialog, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I need three tabs but my code mixes it up with other tabs
there is no CKEditor 4 documentation about this subject

here is my code:

```
            {
                label: 'one',
                elements: [
                    {
                        type: 'text',
                        id: 'img',
                        label: 'imgtext',
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                label: 'two',
                elements: [
                    {
                        type: 'text',
                        label: editor.lang.common.url,
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                label: 'three',
                elements: [
                    {
                        type: 'text',
                        label: editor.lang.common.width,
                    },
                ],
            },
```

I hope you can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find documentation here:

- https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/plugin_sdk_sample_1.html#plugin-dialog-window
- https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/plugin_sdk_sample_2.html#dialog-window-logic
- https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_dialog_definition.html

Please also have a look at [image plugin dialog](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/examples/image.html) and its [code](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/major/plugins/image/dialogs/image.js#L487). This dialog uses 3-5 tabs so it should be a good starting point to create your own.

---

> I need three tabs but my code mixes it up with other tabs

Please note that is very important that each tab has its unique `id` as shown in below code snippet (notice `firsttesttab`, `testtab`and `othertesttab` ids ). If you don't use `ids` then code from all tabs will get mixed up:

```
CKEDITOR.dialog.add( 'abbrDialog', function( editor ) {
    return {

        // Basic properties of the dialog window: title, minimum size.
        title: 'Abbreviation Properties',
        minWidth: 600,
        minHeight: 200,

        // Dialog window content definition.
        contents: [
            {
                // Definition of the Basic Settings dialog tab (page).
                id: 'firsttesttab',
                label: 'First Test Tab',
                // The tab content.
                elements: [
                    {
                        // Text input field for the abbreviation text.
                        type: 'text',
                        id: 'firsttxttest',
                        label: 'First Test Field'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                // Definition of the Basic Settings dialog tab (page).
                id: 'testtab',
                label: 'Test Tab',
                // The tab content.
                elements: [
                    {
                        // Text input field for the abbreviation text.
                        type: 'text',
                        id: 'txttest',
                        label: 'Test Field'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                // Definition of the Basic Settings dialog tab (page).
                id: 'othertesttab',
                label: 'Other Test Tab',
                // The tab content.
                elements: [
                    {
                        // Text input field for the abbreviation text.
                        type: 'text',
                        id: 'othertxttest',
                        label: 'Other Test Field'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],

        // Invoked when the dialog is loaded.
        onShow: function() {
        ...
```

[image]

**NOTE:** It is also important that UI elements inside each tab have unique `ids` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can find documentation here:

- https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/plugin_sdk_sample_1.html#plugin-dialog-window
- https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/plugin_sdk_sample_2.html#dialog-window-logic
- https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_dialog_definition.html

Please also have a look at [image plugin dialog](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/examples/image.html) and its [code](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/major/plugins/image/dialogs/image.js#L487). This dialog uses 3-5 tabs so it should be a good starting point to create your own.

---

> I need three tabs but my code mixes it up with other tabs

Please note that is very important that each tab has its unique `id` as shown in below code snippet (notice `firsttesttab`, `testtab`and `othertesttab` ids ). If you don't use `ids` then code from all tabs will get mixed up:

```
CKEDITOR.dialog.add( 'abbrDialog', function( editor ) {
    return {

        // Basic properties of the dialog window: title, minimum size.
        title: 'Abbreviation Properties',
        minWidth: 600,
        minHeight: 200,

        // Dialog window content definition.
        contents: [
            {
                // Definition of the Basic Settings dialog tab (page).
                id: 'firsttesttab',
                label: 'First Test Tab',
                // The tab content.
                elements: [
                    {
                        // Text input field for the abbreviation text.
                        type: 'text',
                        id: 'firsttxttest',
                        label: 'First Test Field'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                // Definition of the Basic Settings dialog tab (page).
                id: 'testtab',
                label: 'Test Tab',
                // The tab content.
                elements: [
                    {
                        // Text input field for the abbreviation text.
                        type: 'text',
                        id: 'txttest',
                        label: 'Test Field'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                // Definition of the Basic Settings dialog tab (page).
                id: 'othertesttab',
                label: 'Other Test Tab',
                // The tab content.
                elements: [
                    {
                        // Text input field for the abbreviation text.
                        type: 'text',
                        id: 'othertxttest',
                        label: 'Other Test Field'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],

        // Invoked when the dialog is loaded.
        onShow: function() {
        ...
```

[image]

**NOTE:** It is also important that UI elements inside each tab have unique `ids` as well.